# Removing quotation marks while writing CSV files PHP

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

My original csv file was like this:

```
(ID, Country_code, Country, Address, Name, Age, Gender(1 or 0))
001, 1000, "America", "Washington DC", "(Mark", 25, 1
002, 1000, "America", "Washington DC", "Joe", 25, 1
003, 1000, "America, Washington DC", "Chantler)", 25, 1
004, 1001, "Japan", "Tokyo", "(Tanaka", 26, 0
005, 1001, "Japan", "Tokyo", "Satou)", 26, 0
```

After the coding my csv become like this:

```
(ID, Country_code, Country, Address, Name, Age, Gender)

001, 1000, America, Washington DC, (Mark,Joe,Chantler), 25, "1
"
002, 1001, Japan, Tokyo, (Tanaka, Satou), 26, "0
"
```

It automatically includes quotation mark on age and creates the unnecessary line and the quotation mark for the age category.

How could I fix this?

Below is my code (please ignore japanese language comments):

```
<?php
$nl = "\n"; //New line
$t = "\t"; //Tab space
$line = array(); //Multidimensional array
$result = array(); //Joint multidimensional array
$num = 0; 
$num1 = 0; 
$output = array(); //Array convert from multidimension array to single array
$output1 = array(); //Array merge of temp2 and test array

$ar_1=file("KEN_ALL.CSV", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

foreach($ar_1 as $ar1)
{
        $num1++;
        $line[] = explode(',', $array);
}

for($i=0;$i<$num1);$i++)
{
    for($j=0;$j<7;$j++)
    {
    while($j == 0)
    {
        $result[$num][$j] = $line[$i][$j]; 
        $j++;
    }
    while($j == 1)
    {
        $result[$num][$j] = $line[$i][$j]; 
        $j++;
    }
    while($j == 2)
    {
        $line[$i][$j] = str_replace(" ","", $line[$i][$j]); //データ値に空きスペースの削除
        $line[$i][$j] = str_replace('"','', $line[$i][$j]); //データ値に' " 'の削除
        $result[$num][$j] = $line[$i][$j];
        $j++;
    }
    while($j == 3)
    {
        $line[$i][$j] = str_replace(" ","", $line[$i][$j]); //データ値に空きスペースの削除
        $line[$i][$j] = str_replace('"','', $line[$i][$j]); //データ値に' " 'の削除
        $result[$num][$j] = $line[$i][$j]; 
        $j++;
    }
    while($j == 4)
    {
        $line[$i][$j] = str_replace(" ","", $line[$i][$j]); //データ値に空きスペースの削除
        $line[$i][$j] = str_replace('"','', $line[$i][$j]); //データ値に' " 'の削除
        $line[$i+1][$j] = str_replace(" ","", $line[$i+1][$j]); //データ値に空きスペースの削除
        $line[$i+1][$j] = str_replace('"','', $line[$i+1][$j]); //データ値に' " 'の削除
        $result[$num][$j] = $line[$i][$j].$line[$i+1][$j];
        $j++;
    }
    while($j == 5)
    {
        $result[$num][$j] = $line[$i][$j]; 
        $j++;
    }
    while($j == 6)
    {
        $result[$num][$j] = $line[$i][$j]; 
        $j++;
    }
}
$i++;
$num++;
}

function hensyu($v)
{
    return implode(',', $v);
}

$output = array_map("hensyu", $result);


$f_3 = fopen("output.csv") or die ("Unable to open file");
foreach($output as $array)
{
    fputcsv($f_3, explode(',',$array));
}
fclose($f_3);
?>
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Looks like I've edited your questions before. Please refrain from adding "hope to get help", "please help me", "need help ASAP", "it's urgent" and other forms of pleading. They do not help you get answers sooner, but they may get you downvotes. Don't give volunteer editors more work to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to run your script . It showed some php errors and warning , which I have fixed.

```
<?php
$nl = "\n"; //New line
$t = "\t"; //Tab space
$line = array(); //Multidimensional array
$result = array(); //Joint multidimensional array
$num = 0; 
$num1 = 0; 
$output = array(); //Array convert from multidimension array to single array
$output1 = array(); //Array merge of temp2 and test array

$ar_1=file("KEN_ALL.CSV", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

foreach($ar_1 as $ar1)
{
    $num1++;
    $line[] = explode(',', $ar1);
}

for($i=0;$i<$num1;$i++)
{
    for($j=0;$j<7;$j++)
    {
    while($j == 0)
    {
        $result[$num][$j] = $line[$i][$j]; 
        $j++;
    }
    while($j == 1)
    {
        $result[$num][$j] = $line[$i][$j]; 
        $j++;
    }
    while($j == 2)
    {
        $line[$i][$j] = str_replace(" ","", $line[$i][$j]); //データ値に空きスペースの削除
        $line[$i][$j] = str_replace('"','', $line[$i][$j]); //データ値に' " 'の削除
        $result[$num][$j] = $line[$i][$j];
        $j++;
    }
    while($j == 3)
    {
        $line[$i][$j] = str_replace(" ","", $line[$i][$j]); //データ値に空きスペースの削除
        $line[$i][$j] = str_replace('"','', $line[$i][$j]); //データ値に' " 'の削除
        $result[$num][$j] = $line[$i][$j]; 
        $j++;
    }
    while($j == 4)
    {
        $line[$i][$j] = str_replace(" ","", $line[$i][$j]); //データ値に空きスペースの削除
        $line[$i][$j] = str_replace('"','', $line[$i][$j]); //データ値に' " 'の削除
        $line[$i+1][$j] = str_replace(" ","", $line[$i+1][$j]); //データ値に空きスペースの削除
        $line[$i+1][$j] = str_replace('"','', $line[$i+1][$j]); //データ値に' " 'の削除
        $result[$num][$j] = $line[$i][$j].$line[$i+1][$j];
        $j++;
    }
    while($j == 5)
    {
        $result[$num][$j] = $line[$i][$j]; 
        $j++;
    }
    while($j == 6)
    {
        $result[$num][$j] = $line[$i][$j]; 
        $j++;
    }
}
$i++;
$num++;
}

function hensyu($v)
{
    return implode(',', $v);
}

$output = array_map("hensyu", $result);


$f_3 = fopen("output.csv",'a+') or die ("Unable to open file");
foreach($output as $array)
{
    fputcsv($f_3, explode(',',$array));
}
fclose($f_3);
?>
```

And after this , the output it is giving is -

```
(ID," Country_code",Country,Address,Name(Mark," Age"," Gender(1 or 0))"
2,1000,America,WashingtonDC,JoeChantler),25,1
4,1001,Japan,Tokyo,(TanakaSatou),26,0
```

If this output is not correct , Let me know the output you expect.

Comment: I don't need heading in output. I have written heading only for reference. And I want output like this:

Comment: 001, 1000, America, Washington DC, (Mark,Joe,Chantler), 25, 1
<br>    002, 1001, Japan, Tokyo, (Tanaka, Satou), 26, 0

Comment: Infact, my csv output is like this now:

Comment: 001, 1000, America, Washington DC, (Mark,Joe,Chantler), 25, "1 <br>"<br> 002, 1001, Japan, Tokyo, (Tanaka, Satou), 26, "0<br>"

Comment: The problem in my output is it automatically creating quotaion mark on gender and the new line containing quotation mark which i don't need. Would you please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

fputcsv function gets an array as input. You should do:

```
fputcsv($f_3, $array);
```